# Cannot compile SHDocVw in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, delphi-xe6

I recently installed Delphi XE6. Everything works fine but whenever I drop "webbrowser" component on a blank form, the compiler throws error:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(9): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'SHDocVw.pas'

This is the problem regarding delphi only. C++ builder works fine. I have installed lots of third party controls and don't want to reinstall Delphi.

Comment: Try to search for SHDocVw files. Maybe some of those 3rd party controls ships with its own SHDocVw unit.

Comment: I searched. None of those installed components ship with SHDocVw unit.

Comment: Create your own using the type library importer surely

Comment: If XE6 is set up correctly, I don't think it should be trying to compile SHDocVw.Pas, because it should be able to find the relevant copy of SHDocVw.Dcu in one of its Lib folders (32- or 64-bit, depending on your project target).  In any case, you should identify where Delphi is finding the copy of the .Pas file it says it can't compile.

Comment: @David: Will you please reference me how to import type library? By the way, I am new in Delphi.

Comment: @MartynA: Yes, I can see the "SHDocVw.pas" existing in the source directory. Also the corresponding dcu file exists in the lib folder for both debug and release.

Comment: Try renaming the ShDocVw.Pas file temporarily, and see whether your project compiles without error.

Comment: @MartynA: Yes I tried but same problem occurs. [dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(9): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'SHDocVw.pas'

Comment: Ok, I think I found a solution. When I change the build configuration to "Release", the compiler compiles without any error. Should I copy the "SHDocVw.dcu" from release folder of lib directory to that to debug folder? Will it cause any effect in performance?

Comment: Now your project has compiled successfully, I can't really see any point in moving ShDocVW around - it would only mask a future problem when you'd do better to get to the bottom of your current one.  If I were you, I would try and identify what the problem is with compiling your project in the Debug build config.

Comment: You should remove SHDocVw.pas from the project or search path. That's the fundamental problem.